# Изменяющий фон при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Здрасвуйте!
Есть хедер, который имеет прозрачный фон. Как только пользователь начинает скролить страницу вниз - хедеру даётся цвет:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 40) {
        $(".main-header").css("background" , "rgba(255,255,255,1)"); 
        $(".main-header").css("box-shadow" , "0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.2)");
      }

      else{
        $(".main-header").css("background" , "rgba(255,255,255,0)"); 
        $(".main-header").css("box-shadow" , "0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)");
      }
    })
    })
  </script>
```

Однако, если обновить страницу, или обновить страницу после перехода по якорной ссылке - цвет хедера принимает значение по умолчанию, то есть прозрачный.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то исправить данную ситуацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно оформить смену цвета отдельной функцией и запускать ее при скролле и при загрузке страницы.

```js
function changecolor() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 40) {
    $(".main-header").css("background" , "rgba(255,0,255,1)"); 
    $(".main-header").css("box-shadow" , "0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.2)");
  }

  else{
    $(".main-header").css("background" , "rgba(255,0,255,0)"); 
    $(".main-header").css("box-shadow" , "0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)");
  }
}
function function2() {
//еще одна функция выполняющаяся при скролле
};
function function3() {
//еще одна функция на загрузку страницы
};
 $(document).ready(function(){
 
 //это тест для начальной прокрутки стриницы
 //window.scrollBy в вашем варианте не нужен
    window.scrollBy(0,100);
    
    changecolor();
    function3();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       changecolor();
       function2();
       });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-header">
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
<p>
123
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите, а как быть, если скрипт так же меняет не только цвет хедера, но и собственный размер, как и размер элементов в нём. Каждую функцию отдельно?

Comment: Ну так поясните изменения размеров когда происходят. При загрузке страницы? при скроллинге?

Comment: При скролинге. Хедер меняет цвет и размер по высоте при скролинге.

Comment: если нужно несколько функций на событие вешать там немного другой синтаксис. Я для общего случая добавил function2 для скролла и function3 для загрузки. Конечно если код небольшой можно его там сразу прописать вместо создания функций.